# error: package org.apache.commons.math.distribution does not exist

Tags: java, jar

I was trying to run a project but unable to run a java file Utility.java. It cannot import the package in the below statement.

```
import org.apache.commons.math.distribution.*;
```

Since I have a confusion in which path should be included in cp for executing jar file  I tried using the 2 paths commands

```
root@vidhi-VirtualBox:/home/vidhi/Downloads/explorerChain/explorerchain-master# javac -cp "/Downloads/explorerChain/explorerchain-master/commons-math-1.2/commons-math-1.2.jar" Utility.java


root@vidhi-VirtualBox:/home/vidhi/Downloads/explorerChain/explorerchain-master# javac -cp "/commons-math-1.2/commons-math-1.2.jar" Utility.java
```

[Here is the screenshot of the folders depicting location of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6DgU.png)

[Screenshot of commons-math-1.2 folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfUwM.png)

According to me there is an error in location of the files.
P.S. I am beginner in Java. OS is ubuntu

Comment: I think your jar's path is wrong. You are beginning with "/Downloads" which probably does not exist. By "/Downloads" you probably mean the Downloads directory within your home directory and not at the root (/).
Try to put "/home/(YOUR USERNAME)" at the left most of your path. Like: "/home/(YOUR USERNAME)/Downloads/explorerChain/explorerchain-master/commons-math-1.2/commons-math-1.2.jar"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below steps to compile and execute your standalone java program.

I suppose your `target-directory = /home/vidhi/Downloads/explorerChain/explorerchain-master` where you will execute your code.

Copy the jar file `commons-math-1.2.jar` to  location `target-directory`.

```
Command : # cp /source-directory/commons-math-1.2.jar target-directory/
```

Next go to target directory.

```
Command : # cd <target-directory>
```

Next Compile your java file. :

```
Command : # javac -cp commons-math-1.2.jar . Utility.java
```

Next run your compiled java file :

```
Command : # java Utility
```